# Buying a guitar on a music store

Tags: electric-guitar

I am thinking about buying an american fender telecaster. The problem is that in music stores, you try a guitar in store but when you buy it, you don't take the guitar that you try but a guitar that is still boxed up.

My question : Is there any risk of deception while buying a new guitar that you don't get to see?

Comment: I worked in a store selling guitars, whenever someone bought something they got that instrument.  Even if that is not that store's policy I am quite sure if you say I want that one, that is the one you will get.  So if you are worried about it, just insist on the one you played on.  they want the sale, they will not fight that.

Comment: I ordered an acoustic online and got a defect. Your on the right track by buying in a store

Comment: I think it should be no problem to buy the one you've tried. Especially if you pay the full price

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of anyone who would do this in a shop - you always leave with the one you played. Unless you are buying a really cheap starter guitar, perhaps - where it maybe isn't an issue. A proper guitar, like a Tele, is one you don't want to get wrong.

Online is a little different, but you know there is an element of uncertainty online, especially when buying from an unknown source.

Answer (score 2):

Hardly a cheap guitar. Every guitar is subtly different, in the finish, colour, wood grain, feel, etc. Even two consecutively off the assembly line. You have a perfect right to inspect and audition that guitar - belt and zips off though!

If the store has several, you ought to give them all a try. As soon as the store guy refuses, show him the money, and walk away. I bet he'll come running after you! If not, see the manager, and/or take your hard-earned to another store, one which values its customers.

It's also in the store's interest to establish there are no problems with the new guitar out of the box, but I doubt there would be a scam. They could only do that once!

Having read the question again, if you are given an *unboxed guitar* then where's the problem?

Comment: Maybe I did not express well myself.  Some stores give a new guitar with a box from the stock. I don't like this. So, I would like to buy the guitar that I play in store. 
People usually unbox guitars on youtube. Then, I wonder if they are really satisfied by the product. Because, it surprises me to see people buying guitars that they even did not play once before.

Comment: @optimalcontrol I'm repeating what others have said but  I've never been in any shop that wouldn't let you take home the particular instrument you tried  if you're offering them the asking price!

Answer (score 1):

I PREFER TO BUY FROM LOCAL MERCHANTS INSTEAD OF ONLINE.

But the merchant has to be *competitive*.  Remember, they want long-term customers and repeat business.

Demand to try the **actual** guitar you'll buy.  Any new guitar needs to be set-up, so that has to be a part of the price.  Fresh strings in the gauge/brand YOU prefer (you might pay the cost of the set, but the stringing s/b free).  If they charge you for set-up & stringing, walk out.

Demand also: a 30-day return guarantee (may be called 'on-approval').  You take the risk of damage, they take the risk you won't like it...

Are they including a case?  You'll need one, unless you plan to use a pillowcase.

When you buy, also purchase (your expense) a strap, picks, a tuner, a stand (I like Hercules).  For a package with guitar and case, the store ought to work with you for a deal.